# The difference of function declaration in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Let's say we have code like this:

```
interface Vehicle {
    bicycle(): string;
    car(wheel: number): void;
    bus(passanger: number): {
        name: string;
        age: number;
    }[];
}

type Mapper<K extends keyof Vehicle> = (funcName: K, callback: Vehicle[K]) => void;

interface MapperB {
    <K extends keyof Vehicle>(name: K, callback: Vehicle[K]): any;
}

declare const caller: Mapper<keyof Vehicle>;
declare const callerB: MapperB
```

Or typescript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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).

And when i call `caller` and `callerB`, `caller` can't infer the `callback` type according to the first argument. Actually, I found that there is no way to archive that. But `callerB` just does everythings well.

```
caller("bicycle", () => {
    
})// can't give any intellisense

callerB('bus', (passanger) => {
    return [{
        name: 'Jack',
        age: 11
    }]
})// will give perfect hints according to first argument.
```

So I was wondering what's the difference between those two declaration, it doesn't seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One is a generic type that happens to be a function (`Mapper`), the other is a generic function (`MapperB`).

A generic type has its type parameters specified when you declare `caller` so no more inference occurs when you call `caller`. `K` has already been set in stone, and `K` will be the union `'bicycle' | 'car' | 'bus'`. So `callback` will be typed as `Vehicle['bicycle' | 'car' | 'bus']` which will be a union of all function signatures in `Vehicle` which will probably be too permissive for what you want.

A generic function has its type parameters specified (or inferred) when calling the function. So it's at that time based on the type of the argument that `K` is decided to be just `bus` and the callback parameters can be more accurately inferred.

You can declare a generic function with a type alias, but the generic type parameter list must be on the function not on the type:

```
type Mapper = <K extends keyof Vehicle>(funcName: K, callback: Vehicle[K]) => void;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Mapper` type is generic and returns a non-generic function (the type parameters in the function are expanded after receiving a generic type argument), which means `K` is `keyof Vehicle` and not the **specific** key that you're after. The `MapperB` type is not generic, but instead has a generic function, which means that the type variables are expanded on function call, meaning that `K` can be adjusted to be the specific key of `Vehicle`.